# Javascript Unit Testing with Javascript-Test-Driver

Tags: javascript, js-test-driver

Recently a new framework for Javascript unit testing has been released. [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/)
Can anyone points me to some sample examples which I can look at to?

This seems to be an excellent framework; considering that it has command line support and integration with popular IDEs.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers
-Priyank

Comment: +1 for adding js-test-driver tag.  I myself am doing a lot of work with it and asked lots of questions without that tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to get started really is the [JsTestDriver WIKI](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/w/list)
That should give you everything you need to get going.